# Exclude ApplicationStartup Event listener when testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test, springrunner

I recently added an ApplicationStartup class to my SpringBoot project

```
@Component
public class ApplicationStartup
    implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> { ...
```

It implements ApplicationListener.

Now when I run my old JUNit tests that have nothing to do with that class, The testrunner tries to Run my StartupListener, which is neither necessary not appropriate in these cases.

How do I skip the ApplicationListener when my tests initialize?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SubmissionItemManagerTest {...
```

Comment: Are you trying to avoid just one bean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can mock your `ApplicationStartup` class

Add this declaration to your test case:

```
@MockBean
private ApplicationStartup applicationStartup
```

This will create a mocked instance of `ApplicationStartup` and mark it as `@Primary` in your test context thereby replacing the actual instance of`ApplicationStartup`.

Comment: how can u do it when using: @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

Comment: This breaks spring context

Answer (score 5):

You can create a **separate  application** class for testing  and **exclude** the components that are not required for tests:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
        type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, 
        value = { ApplicationStartup.class, 
                 RealApplication.class }))

public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then in your `SubmissionItemManagerTest` class use the `TestApplication` class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
public class SubmissionItemManagerTest {
    ...
}
```